# Add a compound AND condition that allows the loop to continue to iterate only if

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am doing an exercise, these are the requirements:

Use a For loop to step through each position in the winning numbers array and to compare the customer number to each number the array contains.

To complete this, you will need to set up the following.

1. A counter variable (e.g. i) for the loop.
2. A boolean variable (e.g. match) to flag if a match has been found or not.
3. A compound AND condition that allows the loop to continue to iterate only
   if a match is not found, and, the end of the array has not been reached.
4. An if statement nested inside the For loop which checks the customer
   number against each winning number in the array, each time the loop
   iterates, and sets the boolean, match, to true if a match is found.

What I have so far works but I do not understand where requirement 3 would go or the need for it (as the for loop already checks that the end of the array has not been reached? So surely it would only need a single if statement rather than a compound one?), could someone please explain?

What I have so far:

```js
var customerNumbers = 12;
var winningNumbers = [];
var match = false;

// Adds the winning numbers to winningNumbers
winningNumbers.push(12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43);

// Messages that will be shown
var winningMessage = "This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n\n" + winningNumbers + "\n\n";
var customerMessage = "The Customer's Number is:\n\n" + customerNumbers + "\n\n";
var resultMessage = "Sorry, you are not a winner this week.";

// Searches the array to check if the customer number is a winner
for (var i = 0; i < winningNumbers.length; i++) {
 if (customerNumbers == winningNumbers[i]) {
  resultMessage = "We have a match and a winner!"
  match = true;
 }
}

// Result
alert(winningMessage + customerMessage + resultMessage);
```

Comment: Why not just `break` after you get a match?

Comment: I'm asssuming you're supposed to do something like `&& !match` to improve performance? If the loop stops when it has found a match instead of always running through the whole array the program would run a bit faster.

Comment: @jhpratt exactly my thoughts but even the SO wants to know why the exercise demanded the same additional and unwanted compound condition when just breaking out of loop would have sufficed. Understanding the problem is more important unless the exercise really tests the person's improvement skills of the entire problem and solution itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the and statement to the for condition like so.
`for (var i = 0; i < winningNumbers.length && !match; i++) {`

There's no need to change the if statement

```js
var customerNumbers = 12;
var winningNumbers = [];
var match = false;

// Adds the winning numbers to winningNumbers
winningNumbers.push(12, 17, 24, 37, 38, 43);

// Messages that will be shown
var winningMessage = "This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n\n" + winningNumbers + "\n\n";
var customerMessage = "The Customer's Number is:\n\n" + customerNumbers + "\n\n";
var resultMessage = "Sorry, you are not a winner this week.";

// Searches the array to check if the customer number is a winner
for (var i = 0; i < winningNumbers.length && !match; i++) {
 if (customerNumbers == winningNumbers[i]) {
  resultMessage = "We have a match and a winner!"
  match = true;
 }
}

// Result
alert(winningMessage + customerMessage + resultMessage);
```